# Spring Boot - ignore root element in decoding

Tags: spring, jackson

A remote server sends a response in this format

```
{
    "data": {
        "item": {
            a: ...
            b: ...
        }
    }
}
```

In my spring application, I would like to decode this way directly. Instead of creating a Class for data.

```
record Item(String a, String b){}
```

Any idea how it can be done?

I already tried this. but no help.

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true
@JsonRootName("data") 
record Item(String a, String b){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize just the `{"a": "aValue", "b": "bValue"}` json part of your json using the [`JsonNode#at`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#at-java.lang.String-) method that returns a `JsonNode` node that will be converted to your `Item` object with the [`ObjectMapper#treeToValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode-java.lang.Class-) method like below:

```
//pointing to the /data/item node
JsonNode itemNode = mapper.readTree(json).at("/data/item");
//Item will contain a=aValue and b=bValue
Item item = mapper.treeToValue(itemNode, Item.class);
```